# Django - Testing Carrying Over POST Variables

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-unittest

I am working on doing some code coverage unit testing for my Django application when I ran into this interesting predicament.

#### tests/test_views.py

```
class TestLogin(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.url = reverse('account:login')
        self.template = 'account/login.html'

    # This test works
    def test_POST_invalid_login(self):
        response = self.client.post(self.url, {
            'username': 'foo',
            'password': 'bar'
        })
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 401)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, self.template)

    # This is not working as intended.
    def test_POST_no_data(self):
        with self.assertRaises(MultiValueDictKeyError):
            self.client.post(self.url, None)
```

#### views.py

```
class Login(View):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template = 'account/login.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        context = {
            'form': form
        }

        return render(request, self.template, context)

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            # Retrieve the username and password
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']

            # Create a user object from authentication, or return None
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            # Check if user was created
            if user is not None:
                # Login the user to the website
                login(request, user)

                messages.success(request, 'Login successful! Welcome ' + user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name)

                # Eventually have this go to profile pages.
                return redirect('home', permanent=True)
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Login failed: Invalid User.')

        except MultiValueDictKeyError:
            messages.error(request, 'Login failed: Invalid User.')

        # Clear the form since the login attempt failed.
        form = self.form_class(None)

        context = {
            'form': form
        }

        return render(request, self.template, context, status=401)
```

The first test, the `test_POST_invalid_login` sends the data as it suppose to, but the second test, `test_POST_no_data` should not send any data, but the view still recognizes the `foo` and `bar` username and password values thus not catching the exception as it should. I originally written the *no data* test first and it worked originally. I tried moving the test method above the *invalid login* test, and it will still fail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `test_POST_no_data` test asserts that `MultiValueDictKeyError` is raised, but this exception is caught in the view, so the view will never raise it. So, `test_POST_no_data` should be similar to `test_POST_invalid_login`, i.e. should assert the same things.

You can check this is true by writing an empty `raise` statement inside the `except MultiValueDictKeyError:` block. This way, you'll re-raise the same exception and your test will pass.

Comment: That is right, I forgot if an exception is caught in the "unit" it will not be raised unless I explicitly raise the exception in the code via "raise MultiValueDictKeyError".

I'll get back to you later with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Since I want to catch the exception in the code; I decided to refactor the *no data* test to check if it'll get the following assertions. Granted, I could remove the try/except blocks, and check if `request.POST` has the following keys: `username` and `password`, but I want it to fail gracefully and let the app go back to the login page with a failed message instead of contouring with a unit test.

#### tests/test_view.py

```
# Refactored, and working
def test_POST_no_data(self):
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 401)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, self.template)
```

I could bring up another question if this the best way to handle exceptions and testing exceptions, but that'll be another question.

Thanks, Iulia Chiriac, for the answer.